# How can I forward request to one subdomain to another subdomain in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I'm running Apache 2 on Ubuntu and would like to forward all request on one subdomain to another.

Example:

`a.example.com/page.html` would forward to `b.example.com/page.html`

I want to forward **all** requests (not just a few pages).

How would I set that up in my virtual hosts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://b.example.com/$1
```

Comment: Where does that code go?

Comment: Either in your <VirtualHost> section or in a .htaccess file, depending on how you have things set up.

Answer (score 2):

I really wonder why everybody always tries to solve those redirect problems with mod_rewrite rather than [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html).

Put the following line inside the  container of `a.example.com`:

```
RedirectPermanent / http://b.example.com/
```

Comment: That won't redirect `a.example.com/test-page.html` to `b.example.com/test-page.html` as requested by the OP.

Comment: Of course it will! Have you even tried it?

Comment: @ceejayoz: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite - if I could upvote joschi twice, I would.